# Compute correlation using pandas on a dataset with multiple groups

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe like this one with different dates, channels, products and ratings.

```
Date       Channel       Product       Rating
2015-01    Ch1           Pr1           4.0
2015-04    Ch1           Pr1           5.0
2016-02    Ch1           Pr1           4.5
2016-12    Ch1           Pr1           3.4
...
2015-02    Ch1           Pr2           3.0
2015-04    Ch1           Pr2           4.0
2016-07    Ch1           Pr2           3.5
2016-11    Ch1           Pr2           4.3
...
2015-01    Ch2           Pr1           4.0
2015-04    Ch2           Pr1           5.0
2016-02    Ch2           Pr1           4.5
2016-12    Ch2           Pr1           3.4
...
2015-02    Ch2           Pr2           3.0
2015-04    Ch2           Pr2           4.0
2016-07    Ch2           Pr2           3.5
2016-11    Ch2           Pr2           4.3
...
2015-02    Chn           Prm           3.0
2015-04    Chn           Prm           4.0
2016-07    Chn           Prm           3.5
2016-11    Chn           Prm           4.3
```

I have to find correlation matrixes on `Rating` by products and channels by year using `.resample('Y').mean()` on the `Rating` column.
So after that I expect output like:

```
Pr1:
        Ch1    Ch2    ...    Chn
    Ch1 1.0    0.8    ...    -0.3
    Ch2 0.8    1.0    ...    0.6
    ...
    Chn -0.3  0.6     ...    1.0

Pr2:
        Ch1    Ch2    ...    Chn
    Ch1 1.0    0.4    ...    0.5
    Ch2 0.4    1.0    ...    -0.1
    ...
    Chn 0.5    -0.1   ...    1.0

...

Prm:
        Ch1    Ch2    ...    Chn
    Ch1 1.0    0.4    ...    0.5
    Ch2 0.4    1.0    ...    -0.1
    ...
    Chn 0.5    -0.1   ...    1.0
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataset like this

```py
import io
import pandas as pd


tsv = io.StringIO("""Date       Channel       Product       Rating
2015-01    Ch1           Pr1           4.0
2015-04    Ch1           Pr1           5.0
2016-02    Ch1           Pr1           4.5
2016-12    Ch1           Pr1           3.4
2015-02    Ch1           Pr2           3.0
2015-04    Ch1           Pr2           4.0
2016-07    Ch1           Pr2           3.5
2016-11    Ch1           Pr2           4.3
2015-01    Ch2           Pr1           4.0
2015-04    Ch2           Pr1           5.0
2016-02    Ch2           Pr1           4.5
2016-12    Ch2           Pr1           3.4
2015-02    Ch2           Pr2           3.0
2015-04    Ch2           Pr2           4.0
2016-07    Ch2           Pr2           3.5
2016-11    Ch2           Pr2           4.3
2015-02    Chn           Prm           3.0
2015-04    Chn           Prm           4.0
2016-07    Chn           Prm           3.5
2016-11    Chn           Prm           4.3""")

df = pd.read_csv(tsv, sep="\s+", parse_dates=["Date"])
```

1. Compute yearly means for each Channel-Product pair

```
df = df.set_index("Date").groupby(["Channel", "Product"]).resample('Y').mean(numeric_only=True)["Rating"]
```

this will give you something like that

```
Channel  Product  Date      
Ch1      Pr1      2015-12-31    4.50
                  2016-12-31    3.95
         Pr2      2015-12-31    3.50
                  2016-12-31    3.90
Ch2      Pr1      2015-12-31    4.50
                  2016-12-31    3.95
         Pr2      2015-12-31    3.50
                  2016-12-31    3.90
Chn      Prm      2015-12-31    3.50
                  2016-12-31    3.90
```

2. Create a columns of channel values

```
df = df.unstack(level=0)
df
```

The result will be

```
Channel      Ch1            Ch2          Chn         
Product      Pr1  Pr2 Prm   Pr1  Pr2 Prm Pr1 Pr2  Prm
Date                                                 
2015-12-31  4.50  3.5 NaN  4.50  3.5 NaN NaN NaN  3.5
2016-12-31  3.95  3.9 NaN  3.95  3.9 NaN NaN NaN  3.9
```

3. Finally, compute correlations between channels for each product

```
df.groupby(level=0).corr()
```

Result:

```
Channel          Ch1  Ch2  Chn
Product Channel               
Pr1     Ch1      1.0  1.0  NaN
        Ch2      1.0  1.0  NaN
        Chn      NaN  NaN  NaN
Pr2     Ch1      1.0  1.0  NaN
        Ch2      1.0  1.0  NaN
        Chn      NaN  NaN  NaN
Prm     Ch1      NaN  NaN  NaN
        Ch2      NaN  NaN  NaN
        Chn      NaN  NaN  1.0
```